# python get next lines after matching

Tags: python, filtering

I need to grab info about software version and build data (maybe loading file name too) from page [download GIS "Panorama"](http://www.gisinfo.ru/download/download.htm)
I am using python and grab. Now i have sctript like this:

```
from grab import Grab
g = Grab(log_file='out.html')
g.go('http://www.gisinfo.ru/download/download.htm')
for table in g.doc.select('//div[@id="article_header_rubric"]/following-sibling::table[2]'):
#if test.text().startswith('Профессиона'):
 for tr in table.select('tr'):
  type(tr.select('td'))
  for td in tr.select('td'):
   #if td.text().startswith('Профессиональная ГИС'):
   print (td.text())
```

And result is like this:

```
Драйвер электронного ключа x86 (версия 6.20, 32-разрядные операционные системы,
для Панорама 10 и выше)
15.08.2013
9,6 Mb
drivers.zip

Сервер Guardant Net (версия 5.5.0.10, для Панорама 10 и 11)
25.07.2013
4.1 Mb
gnserver.zip

Сервер Guardant Net (версия 6.3.1.713, для Панорама 12)
11.10.2016
4 Mb
netkey6.zip

Программа для диагностики ключей
13.07.2016
2,6 Mb
diagnostics.zip
```

Than i filtering what i want:

```
from grab import Grab
g = Grab(log_file='out.html')
g.go('http://www.gisinfo.ru/download/download.htm')
for table in g.doc.select('//div[@id="article_header_rubric"]/following-sibling::table[2]'):
#if test.text().startswith('Профессиона'):
 for tr in table.select('tr'):
  type(tr.select('td'))
  for td in tr.select('td'):
   if td.text().startswith('Профессиональная ГИС'):
    print (td.text())
```

And result now:

```
Профессиональная ГИС
Профессиональная ГИС "Панорама" (версия 12.4.0, для платформы "x64")
Профессиональная ГИС "Панорама" (версия 12.3.2, для платформы "x64", на английском языке)
Профессиональная ГИС "Карта 2011" (версия 11.13.5.7)
```

But i want result like this:

```
Профессиональная ГИС "Панорама" (версия 12.4.0, для платформы "x64")
29.12.2016
347 Mb
panorama12x64.zip

Профессиональная ГИС "Панорама" (версия 12.3.2, для платформы "x64", на английском языке)
24.11.2016
376 Mb
panorama12x64en.zip

Профессиональная ГИС "Карта 2011" (версия 11.13.5.7)
11.01.2017
263 Mb
panorama11.zip
```

And ideas?

Comment: It is unclear to me what is meant by `some lines after mathing`.

Comment: i want something like this                                                   `Профессиональная ГИС "Карта 2011" (версия 11.13.5.7)
11.01.2017
263 Mb
panorama11.zip`

Comment: I am sorry, this still is not clear to me.  Please provide an example of what you want by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

`tr.select('td')` returns an iterable. In you current code, you test the string on each iteration, so you only print the first one.

You should store an iterator, take its first value and test it, and if it matches print all values from the iterable:

```
 for tr in table.select('tr'):
  type(tr.select('td'))
  it = iter(tr.select('td'))
  td = next(it)      # process first field in row
  if td.text().startswith('Профессиональная ГИС'):
    print (td.text())
    for td in it:    # print remaining fields
      print(td.text())
```

Comment: Thank you, i have tried, but`TypeError: 'SelectorList' object is not an iterator`

Comment: and result is firts matching=) does exist in python something like grep?

Answer (score 0):

is ok for me like this:

```
from grab import Grab
g = Grab(log_file='out.html')
g.go('http://www.gisinfo.ru/download/download.htm')
list = []
for table in g.doc.select('//div[@id="article_header_rubric"]/following-sibling::table[2]'):
 for tr in table.select('tr'):
  type(tr.select('td'))
  for td in tr.select('td'):
    list.append(td.text())
for i in list:
 indexi=list.index(i)
 if (i.startswith('Профессиональная ГИС "Панорама" (версия 12') and i.endswith('x64")')):
  panorama12onsite = list[indexi]
  panorama12onsitedata = list[indexi+1]
 elif i.startswith('Профессиональная ГИС "Карта 2011"'):
  panorama11onsite = list[indexi]
  panorama11onsitedata = list[indexi+1]
 elif (i.startswith('Профессиональный векторизатор "Панорама-редактор" (версия 12') and i.endswith('x64")')):
  panedit12onsite = list[indexi]
  panedit12onsitedata = list[indexi+1]
 elif i.startswith('Профессиональный векторизатор "Панорама-редактор" (версия 11'):
  panedit11onsite = list[indexi]
  panedit11onsitedata = list[indexi+1]
  print (panorama12onsite)
  print (panorama12onsitedata)
  print (panorama11onsite)
  print (panorama11onsitedata)
  print (panedit12onsite)
  print (panedit12onsitedata)
  print (panedit11onsite)
  print (panedit11onsitedata)
```

Now i can use this variables in other part of script (merge vs downloaded version and download new if exists). Thanks all for help